# Firefox/Chrome devtools mode causes CORS errors with VSCode Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, cors, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

**Launching Chrome/Firefox from VSCode Debugger (runs in DevTools mode) always gives CORS error for API request, but works fine in normal Firefox/Chrome browser.**

Using Laravel for API with [CORS enabled](https://medium.com/@martinsOnuoha/fix-cors-issues-in-laravel-apis-bad89bed0150). Nextjs (React) for frontend, my api request https://site.test/api/info from the frontend https://localhost:3000/home works fine when using Firefox/Chrome normally.

However, as soon as I use the VSCode Debugger (with Firefox Debugger extension installed), it would give a CORS error in the console.

launch.json (For VS Code Debugger)

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Firefox against localhost",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/home",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "webpack://_n_e",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Firefox DevTools mode CORS error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://site.test/api/info. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Not being able to access the debugger and breakpoints ain't fun.

Comment: The “CORS request did not succeed” error message actually indicates the problem is something other than CORS-related. It literally means the request failed to be sent successfully. Or in other words, it means the transaction never reached the point of getting a response from the server you’re trying to send the request to. So it can often indicate a failure at the network level — such as an SSL failure. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

Comment: I wonder if Firefox devtools mode messes with the https/http state. I have to proxy localhost (nextjs server) to be https for it to work in a standard Firefox browser.

Comment: Might be good to ask in the #devtools room on Mozilla’s Matrix server at https://matrix.to/#/@mozilla-irc:matrix.org

Comment: I'll check that out, although the issue also occurs in Chrome devtools, and works normally in standard Chrome. Just used Firefox as the main example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working and it took two things.

1. Open up the url of the backend when vscode opens Firefox to debug something. For example, my api is running here: https://localhost:7188/api/. I opened up https://localhost:7188/swagger/index.html.

If the certificate is self-signed and it gives security warnings, allow it and continue.

2. For some reason, when you are debugging from VSCode, it isn't seeing the request as coming from what the URL says in your browser.

On the webApi server, I had it set to allow https://localhost:8080/. This works from a normal browser, but fails when Firefox is under "remote control".

I had to change my CORS policy from allowing https://localhost:8080/ to allowing any origin. It then went right to work.

```
options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
            policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
                //.WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");
            });
```

The only issue remaining is that it seems that I have to accept the self-signed certificate every time I start debugging from VSCode. I hope I don't have to accept it every time for the api side, as well.

Not sure, but there could be a way to import the certificates into Firefox so that it remembers them while under "remote control".

There is a way to do that in Chrome, but I tried it and it didn't work for my certificate.

Comment: CORS issues top my list of things that have caused me to waste the most time instead of actually working. I wish Chrome and Firefox would allow disabling of CORS on localhost. I know this would be possible for either of them. I had some plugins that disabled CORS, but it seems they aren't working any more.

Comment: Plugins get auto disabled under "remote control/dev" mode in Firefox and Chrome. You can reinstall it after browser launch, but they'd disappear on close.